# Programming Apache spark 2.0 with kotlin

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin, apache-spark-sql

I want to use kotlin for programming in Spark 2.0.

I added spark's jar files and I can use JavaSparkContext in my code but Can not use kotlin in spark 2.0.

when I use SparkSession like this:

```
SparkSession sc = SparkSession.builder(). ...
```

I get this error: Unresolved refrence: sparkSession

Is it possible to use Kotlin for programming in Spark 2.0? If yes, How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Kotlin for programming in Spark 2.0?

Yes, it's a JVM language with very good Java interoperation, and Spark can be used from Java.

> If yes, How can I do that?

Take the Java examples (not the Scala ones) and [convert them to Kotlin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html).

```
SparkSession sc = SparkSession.builder()
```

isn't legal Kotlin (and wouldn't produce the error you give, since it doesn't have any mention of `sparkSession`). It should be

```
val sc = ...
```

or

```
val sc: SparkSession = ...
```

Comment: Have you created `udf`s in `kotlin` for use with `DataFrame`'s ? that would be quite interesting to see

Answer (score 0):

And now there is a special API created by JetBrains to work with Spark from Kotlin! You can check it [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spark-api).

Of course it eve supports the latest (as of time of writing this) Spark 3.2